# Пунктуация при "внутренней" прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант расстановки знаков препинания более корректный.

**1 случай:**

**а)** Вы произносите фразу, а ваш партнёр говорит: "Верю" или "Не верю". Результат считается достигнутым, когда партнёр скажет: "Верю" - десять раз подряд.

**б)** Вы произносите фразу, а ваш партнёр говорит "верю" или "не верю". Результат считается достигнутым, когда партнёр скажет "верю" десять раз подряд.

**2 случай:**

**а)** Я раньше тоже думал, что фраза: "Все будет хорошо!" - вселяет надежду.

**б)** Я раньше тоже думал, что фраза "Все будет хорошо!" вселяет надежду.

Answer (score 3):

***Вы произносите фразу, а ваш партнёр говорит "верю" или "не верю". Результат считается достигнутым, когда партнёр скажет "верю" десять раз подряд.*** - Здесь "верю" и "не верю" употреблены в значении "слово верю" и "слово не верю" , реальной речевой ситуации здесь  нет, поэтому оформлять в виде прямой речи их не надо, просто берём в кавычки. Предложение не перегружено знаками, выглядит красиво и правильно.

***Ср.: Партнёр громко и отчётливо сказал: "Верю!"***

***Я раньше тоже думал, что фраза "Все будет хорошо!" вселяет надежду.***

Фраза *какая?* - *Всё будет хорошо!* - Здесь предложение в кавычках является несогласованным определением при подлежащем "фраза", а уже после него идёт сказуемое "вселяет надежду".

Предложение с прямой речью предполагает слова автора, которые содержат в себе указание на говорящего, на обстоятельства или способ высказывания. Здесь ничего такого нет. Поэтому двоеточие не ставим.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:  ***С тех пор беспаловская фраза «Из всех искусств мы предпочитаем многотиражное» популярна в журналистской среде.***  (Александр Садчиков) ***Это обидно, и фраза «Не волнуйся, мами, ничего плохого с тобой не случится» мало утешает в подобной ситуации.*** [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]

И всё же постановка двоеточия в предложениях со словом "фраза" не является ошибкой, особенно если сказуемое находится в препозиции к слову "фраза", а также если при слове "фраза" есть указательное слово. Примеры из Нацкорпуса: ***Есть такая замечательная фраза: «Все, что с вами происходит, зачем-то вам нужно».***    ***Особенно больно резанула Ольгу фраза: «Помочь человеку может только другой человек».*** [Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)